# Managing multiple Xcode projects that share code with git

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git, workspace

There are already several SO questions that address this issue, but I haven't found one that completes addresses my situation.

I have projects X, Y, and Z, that all share a common framework C. The projects and the framework all use Cocoapods. I would ideally have three separate Xcode projects that all include the common framework C. So I would have, X+C, Y+C, and Z+C. Then, when I push X+C, I want it to push the changes of X to repository X, and the changes of C to repository C. I would also like to be able to pull changes from C into X, Y, or Z. I would like to work on framework from within project X, Y, or Z, and debug the framework from each of the projects X, Y, or Z.

Is this currently possible? I know there is the concept of submodules, but it doesn't sound very robust (likely to fail with branches).

Comment: Yes it's possible with pods. You can create private framework `C`

Comment: So my framework would become a Pod? I've tried this approach, but it didn't seem to allow me to work on the framework in real-time. I had to update the framework every time. Or is there another way?

Comment: No. If you define path for your `C` framework in podfile then it'll be generated as `development pods` and you can debug and edit it.

(example `pod 'Alamofire', :path => '~/Documents/Alamofire'`)

Comment: I would then define the path to be outside of any of my projects' paths. Each project would have a Podfile that refers to this path. I would just have to make sure that I define the path correctly on each machine where I clone the repository. I assume a relative path would be helpful in this case?

Comment: Yes a relative path its good idea. You can define framework in this same git repository or add submodule for your git repository project

Comment: I don't want it in the same git repository, but I'm not sure a submodule would be necessary either since the directory is outside any of projects' directories. Why not just a separate git repository?

Comment: I used a separate git repository and it is working perfectly. Do you want to write up your answer so I can vote for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible with pods. You can create private framework `C`.

If you define path for your `C` framework in podfile for your projects then the framework will be generated as development pods and you can debug and edit it.

#### Example part of podfile

```
'C', :path => './C/Source')
```

You can use relative path. Also you can define framework in this same git repository or add submodule for your git repository project